# How to replace set or group of characters with string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple script replacing all occurrences of certain group or set of characters (or set of strings) in text.

In this case I will try to replace all letters "a,e,i,o,u" with certain string.

My script:

```
def replace_all(text, repl):
    text1 = text.replace("a", repl)
    text2 = text1.replace("e", repl)
    text3 = text2.replace("i", repl)
    text4 = text3.replace("o", repl)
    text5 = text4.replace("u", repl)
    return text5
```

Is there any simpler way of doing it? What if I need to replace bigger group of chars or strings? Chaining it like this does not seem to be really effective then.

This is maybe a primitive question. However, I am still in learning phase so maybe I get it in later lessons. Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My knowledge tells me there are `3` different ways of doing this, all of which are shorter than your method:

- Using a `for-loop`
- Using a `generator-comprehension`
- Using `regular expressions`

---

First, using a `for-loop`. This is probably the most straight-forward improvement to your code and essentially just reduces the `5` lines with `.replace` on down to `2`:

```
def replace_all(text, repl):
    for c in "aeiou":
        text = text.replace(c, repl)
    return text
```

---

You could also do it in one-line using a `generator-comprehension`, combined with the `str.join` method. This would be faster (if that is of importance) as it is of complexity `O(n)` since we will go through each character and evaluate it once *(the first method is complexity `O(n^5)` as Python will loop through `text` five times for the different replaces)*.

So, this method is simply:

```
def replace_all(text, repl):
    return ''.join(repl if c in 'aeiou' else c for c in text)
```

---

Finally, we can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to substitute all of the characters in the set: `[aeiou]` with the text `repl`. This is the shortest of the solutions and probably what I would recommend:

```
import re
def replace_all(text, repl):
    return re.sub('[aeiou]', repl, text)
```

---

As I said at the start, all these methods complete the task so there is no point me providing individual test cases but they do work as seen in this test:

```
>>> replace_all('hello world', 'x')
'hxllx wxrld'
```

---

**Update**

A new method has been brought to my attention: `str.translate`.

```
>>> {c:'x' for c in 'aeiou'}
{'a': 'x', 'e': 'x', 'i': 'x', 'o': 'x', 'u': 'x'}
>>> 'hello world'.translate({ord(c):'x' for c in 'aeiou'})
'hxllx wxrld'
```

This method is also `O(n)`, so just as efficient as the previous two.

Comment: What about str.translate()? and why this is a good or a bad idea?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Never encountered that method before! See my update. I don't know what you mean by "good" or "bad" - you can do whatever you want so long as it is as efficient as is required, which I would expect this method to be.

Comment: I am surprised that you have not encounter before. See this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56378872/replace-multiple-special-characters-most-efficient-way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fine place for a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html):

```
import re

def replace_all(text, repl):
    return re.sub('[aeiou]', repl, text)
```

This will work for the case in your question, where you're replacing single characters. If you want to replace a set of longer strings:

```
def replace_all(text, to_replace, replacement):
    pattern = '|'.join(to_replace)
    return re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)

>>> replace_all('this is a thing', ['thi','a'], 'x')
'xs is x xng'
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you're doing is perfectly valid, however there are better ways.

Here are some solutions, with runtimes taken over 100000 loops.

#### The main signature:

Targets are the characters you want to replace, repl is the replacement character.

```
def replace_all(text, targets=['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'], repl='_'):
    text = # Something here to swap characters as an array
    return ''.join(text) # Stitch it back together
```

#### Bytearray

[Bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) Is a mutable data structure that contains a list of the characters themselves. As a data structure, it is seemingly the ideal choice, strings in python are immutable, this works around that to prevent constant construction/destruction.

```
[chr(c) if chr(c) not in targets else repl for c in bytearray(text, 'utf-8')]
```

Runs in 0.365

#### Without bytearray

This operates on a simple list, the list itself is mutable, but the characters are strings, therefore there is some modification of technically immutable structures here.

```
[c if c not in targets else repl for c in text]
```

runs in 0.179

#### Map

This maps the function onto each character in the string.

```
map(lambda c: c if c not in targets else repl, text)
```

Runs in 0.265