# How to remove a number from alphanumeric string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

a string is given with alphabets and numbers. for example 1256Ab79.

We have to remove 56 and 7 where ever it occurs from the string.

Input:

1256Ab79

Output:

12Ab9

Input:

a567Eq79

Output:

aEq9

I tried .isdigits()  functions but i'm not able to slove that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace set or group of characters with string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350607/how-to-replace-set-or-group-of-characters-with-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain 2 [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace) together. For this specific and very simple case:

```
>>> s = '1256Ab79'
>>> s.replace('56', '').replace('7', '')
'12Ab9'
>>> s = 'a567Eq79'
>>> s.replace('56', '').replace('7', '')
'aEq9'
```

The first `replace()` replaces any instance of the sub-string `'56'` with an empty string, effectively removing it. Likewise the second removes `'7'` from the string. Note that we can chain multiple calls to `replace()` together because `replace()` returns the modified string.

If you require more complex replacements, or there are a great many possible target strings, then you could look at `re.sub()` and dynamically construct the regex pattern from a list of possible target strings.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can be used for this purpose:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\W+', '', your_string)
```

By Python definition ... `'\W == [^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, this will  excludes all numbers, letters and _

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `re.sub()` with the regular expression `56|7`

```py
import re

word = '1256Ab79'
re.sub(r'56|7', '', word)
```

```
12Ab9
```